# How to Compress an access data base with zipfile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to zip a microsoft data base with my script. The script works but the data base is still the same size

```
import zipfile
zipfile.ZipFile('roads.zip', mode='w').write("roads.mdb")
```

I want the data zipped and reduced in size (like zip does normally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipFile` does not compress files by default. You should pass to the constructor `compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` if you want the files compressed:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('roads.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    zip.write("roads.mdb")
```

Comment: It aint working. Now there is no zip file being made!?

Comment: You would have to close the `ZipFile` handle for the write buffer to flush. Use the `with` statement to let the context manager handle it for you. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have tried with but nothing happen. I'm using python 2.7.8 by the way

Comment: I just corrected a typo. The argument should be `compression`, not `compress`. Can you try again?